# c++ template result type

Tags: c++, templates

In my Qt-project I often need to access the current date/time. Since this value is required with different data types ( esp. string types ) , I wrote the following template:

```
   /* used constants */
   const bool UTC_TIME = true;
   const bool LOCAL_TIME = !UTC_TIME;
   const char* vsoft::iot_opcua::Constants::DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz";

   template< class T = QDateTime >
   auto curDateTime( const bool acbAsUTC = LOCAL_TIME ) -> std::conditional_t< ( std::is_same< T, QString     >::value ) ||
                                                                               ( std::is_same< T, std::string >::value ) ||
                                                                               ( std::is_same< T, char*       >::value ) ||
                                                                               ( std::is_same< T, const char* >::value )
                                                                               , T          /* explicit string cast */
                                                                               , QDateTime  /* default return type  */
                                                                             >
   {
      QDateTime lDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );

      if ( acbAsUTC )
      {
         lDateTime = lDateTime.toUTC();
      }


      if constexpr ( std::is_same< T, QString >::value )
      {
         return lDateTime.toString( vsoft::iot_opcua::Constants::DateTimeFormat );
      }

      if constexpr ( std::is_same< T, std::string >::value )
      {
         return lDateTime.toString( vsoft::iot_opcua::Constants::DateTimeFormat ).toStdString();
      }

      if constexpr ( ( std::is_same< T, char* >::value ) || ( std::is_same< T, const char* >::value ) )    
      {
         return lDateTime.toString( vsoft::iot_opcua::Constants::DateTimeFormat ).toStdString().c_str();
      }

      return lDateTime;
   }
```

But the compiler says compiler error C2440: "return: cannot convert from 'QDateTime' to 'QString'" in the last line

```
return lDateTime;
```

Why does the compiler want to cast? All explicitly permitted return types have been handled before, so the only remaining return type should be QDateTime.

Comment: You try to return different types. For instance, lDateTime.toString and lDateTime

Comment: This does not answer your question, but why don't you just use template specializations (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). I think that would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning different types in the same function. Make sure all the expressions are evaluated at compile-time.

```
if constexpr (...)
    return ...;
else if constexpr ( ... )
    return ...;
else
    return default_value;
```

Your line `return lDateTime;` should be in a `constepxr if/else`.

Comment: I only permit some string return types, in all other cases QDateTime should be returned. This is to prevent some call like `curDateTime< int >()`.

All my permitted return types that differs from `QDateType` are handled within the template.

Comment: But I added the `else` and it works. Small change, big effect. I didn't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @SoerenZimmermann Yes, because with the else, you are not returning 2 types in 1 function, but 1 type per function.